# how to apply fonts to our website that included in our project

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-5

I have downloaded the font family and I have added that font family in my asp.net mvc5 project. I want to know How to apply that font family in my website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what format was font downloaded? Do you have all the formats needed to use them on your site (woff2, eot, ttf)

Comment: The fonts are in ttf format. And I have all the fonts available